# Get text from DB after the second P tag <p> using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a news table in my Database, this table has a Column named TheNews, content the HTML tags with the text.

I want to select the text located between the second `<p>` tag.

for example I have this text :

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>The text that I want </p>
<p>other text</p>
```

I want to select this text '**The text that I want**' using SQL on MySQL.

I try to use this query, but I need to specify the order of tag:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(TheNews, '<p>', -1),
                       '</p>', 1)
FROM news;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work in every situation you encounter, but it works here I believe:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("<p>Hello</p>
<p>The text that I want </p>
<p>other text</p>", "</p>", 2), "<p>", -1)
```

It would be nice if mysql had a proper `strtok` implementation.

Comment: it's work, please modify to this : SELECT `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TheNews, "</p>", 2), "<p>", -1) FROM news`